# Creating a custom Vagrantfile from Packer

Tags: ruby, vagrant, packer

I've been trying to figure out how to create a custom vagrant file from packer, I understand that in the `post-processor` section you will define a directory from which to scrap from, what I do not understand is if there needs to be a specifically named file inside as to which to gather data from.

```
"post-processors": [{
  "vagrantfile_template": "configs/vagrantfile_template",
  "type": "vagrant"
}],
```

The above code to my knowledge would look under `configs/vagrantfile_template`, but what would need to be in here? Would I create a `Vagrantfile` and place it there, or would it need to be a specifically named Ruby file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `vagrantfile_template` option in a `vagrant` post-processor points directly to a file and not a directory [0]. The contents of this file should be structured like a normal Vagrantfile and contain any customizations for the box artifact that you are creating.

For example, if you wanted users of your custom Vagrant box to not have the `/vagrant` shared folder mounted by default, your `Vagrantfile` template might look like this...

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.synced_folder \
    ".",
    "/vagrant",
    :disabled => true
end
```

#### Resources

- [0]: https://github.com/mitchellh/packer/blob/53b1db16692c7bf2e654ac125b8676c02154d07a/post-processor/vagrant/post-processor.go#L113-L138